# Which is correct? Who or Whom?

Tags: word-usage, pronouns

We heard this sentence in the movie ***Northmen***.

> These weapons are all that are left of men, **whom**, like you, confronted me.

Which is correct?

I think it should be **who** and not **whom** because in the affirmative the sentence becomes

> These men confronted me

which should be replaced by **who**.
My friend says the replacing pronoun should be **whom** because it refers to people.

Comment: Okay, so an important thing to note before we get into what is "correct": outside of the current most formal styles, "whom" is dead in modern English. It doesn't matter whether it would have been correct a hundred years ago, you couldn't get the majority of modern English speakers to remember or confirm which is a correct or incorrect usage. "Who" is used indiscriminately for what would have been either "who" or "whom" before.

Comment: I just realized there's a chance this is only true in American English, but I'd be surprised if it wasn't the case in all major English speaking communities. Could others please confirm?

Comment: How modern? I learned it proper in school and I am nowhere near 100 years old. And do you mean just casual usage, or even in university now they don't care? (AmE)

Comment: I said a hundred as that's about the time period I expect the majority of literate English speakers would be able to acknowledge when to use one or the other. It was an estimate, of course. I know it's been taught to at least some over the intervening time, but it most definitely seems to me that it's as often forgotten as remembered, and that incorrect ideas like "whom refers to a person" are as widely held as the correct usage, and there is, outside of dead references, not much consensus among speakers.

Comment: I combine that with the fact that very few would confront someone using "who" instead of "whom", or indeed even notice anything was wrong, and that it is no longer taught in elementary schools because the teachers there can't remember the actual rule themselves (I asked them at the time), and I think "dead" is a pretty fair assessment. At least as dead as not splitting infinitives.

Comment: I'm a rather militant descriptivist, so I'm very sorry if I'm stepping on people's toes.

Comment: [Who and whom](http://ell.stackexchange.com/search?q=Who+whom) ad nauseum here on ELL as well as ELU, [which see](http://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=Who+whom+&tab=relevance)

Answer (score 1):

"Who" is used for subjects, "whom" is used for objects. Examples:

> the men who confronted me.
>   (They (subject) confronted me.)
>
> the men whom I confronted.
>   (I confronted them(object).)

So "who" is correct here.

Comment: This is indeed the rule.  But it should also be noted that using "who" for everything is at that cusp in the evolution of a language where many people consider it correct.  Most people hardly notice the incorrect use of "who", but an incorrect use of "whom" sounds ludicrously pretentious.

Comment: You apparently missed my rant about that in the question's comments. :)

Comment: Your observations are correct, but you forgot to say that *who* is also used for Objects.

Comment: Well, it's not *supposed* to be used for objects, but see above two rants about militant prescriptivism. I'd just as soon not acknowledge that this rule exists at all.

Answer (score 1):

If *who(m)* is after a preposition you need to use *whom*. If the word *who(m)* occurs directly before a verb you must use *who*. In other circumstances it doesn't matter what you use, but my opinion is that it's better to use *who*. That's just my opinion; native-speakers use both.  If you stick to the two important rules, you'll sound like a native-speaker.

Comment: ...this is even more confusing than the "whom refers to a person" rule. Your second rule is a convoluted way of saying that "who refers to the subject of a phrase", but I don't think your first rule is right. Two major examples: "He Who Shall Not Be Named" from Harry Potter, and "He who is without sin cast the first stone" which is a popular misquotation from the Bible. (Or at least, I can't find the translation which uses that phrasing. Many of them say "that" instead of "who".)

Comment: Aaaaarrrgh! Thanks @modulusshift. That should be "preposition" not pronoun!!!!!!